# R Reshaping Data from long to wide by aggregating on a variable

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

I have row-wise transaction data in the following long format

```
TransactionId ItemCode
101   123
101   521
102   423
103   871
103   982
103   131
```

I want to reshape this to get all items in one transaction in one row, so the new reshaped table looks like this (wide)

```
TransactionID ItemCode(s)
101   123   521
102   423
103   871   982   131
```

I have tried melting and casting in R, but i am a bit confused about the how the methods work. Also my dataset is huge, it has 30M rows. How should I go about this process?

Comment: your output table isn't in rectangular form. You have too few columns relative to data below it (which has three columns)

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian I edited the transaction ids, maybe this makes what I want to do more clear. My rows will not always have the same number of outputs, because transactions can have variable number of items in them.

Comment: Do you want your item codes in separate columns or in one column, and if in one column, do you want them as a character vector or as a data.frame per cell?

Comment: @aichao multiple columns is fine, with one item code in each cell in a row.

Comment: I just tried `dcast(products_sample, TransactionID~ ItemCode)`, this gives me a sparse matrix with all the item codes as columns and the transaction ids as row names. Can i convert this into a format described above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `plyr` package to accomplish what you want. Assuming your data is in the data frame `products_sample`, you can use `ddply` with `spread` from the `tidyr` package. This will put the different `ItemCodes` from each `TransactionId` into different columns.

```
library(plyr)
library(tidyr)
result <- ddply(products_sample, "TransactionId", spread, ItemCode, ItemCode)
```

Using the data you provided:

```
  TransactionId ItemCode
1           101      123
2           101      521
3           102      423
4           103      871
5           103      982
6           103      123
```

This gives

```
print(result)
##  TransactionId 123 521 423 131 871 982
##1           101 123 521  NA  NA  NA  NA
##2           102  NA  NA 423  NA  NA  NA
##3           103  NA  NA  NA 131 871 982
```

The last two arguments to `ddply` are the `key` and `value` arguments passed to `spread`. The `key` identifies the column in `products_sample` whose values are to be used as the column names. The `value` identifies the column in `products_sample` whose values will populate the cells. See `?spread` for details.

Comment: thanks! why are you specifying `ItemCode` twice? when i tried running this, i get the error: `Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2)`

Comment: @SuhrudL: one possible cause for your error message is that you used `TransactionId` as the key in spread. Recall that this spread operation is performed with the data grouped by `TransactionId`, the second argument in `ddply`. Consequently, the identifiers for the `key` will be the same for all rows in the `spread`.